# Defining an IDL class with an array of unknown size as a member variable

Tags: arrays, class, idl-programming-language

I'm relatively new to IDL, so I'm sure what I want to do is actually quite trivial!

I'm creating a class with a few member variables.  Two of these will just be floats, but the third I would like to be an 3-dimensional array with unknown size (well.. actually I know the size of the third dimension to be 12, but that's it!).  How do I declare this in the class definition or is it not possible?  Maybe I need to work with a non-array data structure..?

Here's my code so far:

```
pro field__define
  void={field, lat_res: 0.0, long_res: 0.0, values: ?!?!?!?!}
  return
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a pointer, like:

```
pro field__define
  void = { field, lat_res: 0.0, long_res: 0.0, values: ptr_new() }
end
```

By the way, there is no need for a `RETURN` in the definition, execution returns when it hits an `END` statement.

This does not actually create a pointer, it just saves space for the pointer. When you want to use the field, you will need to do something like:

```
self.values = ptr_new(fltarr(3, 4, 5))
```

Then use the values like:

```
help, *self.values
```

Lastly then don't forget to clean up the heap when you are done with array with:

```
ptr_free, self.values
```

It might be good to get a book for topics like this, there are a lot of details that following a few examples through can help with.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate technique that uses a hash to represent the member variables of a class is outlined [here](http://idldatapoint.com/2012/01/05/a-technique-for-flexible-getsetproperty-methods-in-idl-8/). It has an advantage in that it's arguably easier to work with hashes than with pointers in IDL, but it requires at least IDL version 8 to run.